# How do I validate that value entered into an input box is just numbers?

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering what the best and easiest way was to ensure that the value a user enters into an input box is numeric in a web page? either notify them they are not allowed to when they edit it or not allow them to enter in non numeric values to begin with.

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Are real numbers allowed ? Or just integers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric

Comment: try to take the square root, trap for errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If only integer values are allowed, I would try something like:

```
if( isNaN(parseInt(str, 10)) ) {
    //error
}
```

EDIT:
@M28 and @unomi are right, this might allow some inputs that aren't really numbers. M28 posted a *really* good solution in the comments:

```
if( ! (parseInt(str, 10).toString() == str) ) {
    //error
}
```

Comment: Do you prefer this method over tryparse()?

Comment: Please, use the second parameter when calling parseInt

Comment: @mcass20 Don't know what `tryparse` is :">

Comment: You could also do: `parseInt(str, 10).toString()==str` if you want a yet more strict check.

Comment: Oh, sorry! Int32.TryParse()
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Comment: +1,for trick to avoid hexadecimal treated as numeric value-- since its passing isNaN test

Comment: input "00" fails since `parseInt` gives 0

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression ^\d*$

```
var re = new RegExp("^\d*$");
  if ($("#someinput").val().match(re)) {
    alert("Only numbers");
  } else {
    alert("No match");
  }

^ tells the expression to start matching from the beginning of the string. 
\d is a match for numbers which is the same as [0-9] (any number from 0 to 9)
* tells to match all numbers in string.
$ tells the expression to match until the end of the string.
```

The $("#someinput").val() is jquery but you could use normal javascript as in:
document.somepintput.value.match(re).

regular expressions are well worth learning as they can solve many problems in a neat and concise manner. [Regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Comment: Or you can use a regular expression.

Comment: can you please expand on that answer? I'm not really familiar with it, really appreciated thanks

Comment: I think it won't allow float values .

Answer (score 3):

While nc3b is close, using parseInt will actually allow cases you might not want it to.

```
parseInt("133t",10)
```

results in: 133

Better to do

```
if(isNaN(Number(str, 10)){
  Error;
}
```

If you want to make sure that the whole string must be representative of a number.

Answer (score 2):

I use jquery and a AlphaNumeric plugin, see here for a [demo](http://www.itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/)

Comment: Hi

i have <input class="datapoints" type="text" name="delayed_periods_to_alarm" size="5" />

and i put in:

<script type="text/javascript">
 
$('.datapoints').numeric(); 
</script>

at the bottom but it gives me a $(".datapoints").numeric is not a function error.

thanks

Comment: im sorry i dont know how to highlight the code in my comment, really sorry.

Comment: Not sure without reviewing your code, maybe try and give your input an id='myid' and use $('myid').numeric(), also make sure you reference BOTH jquery and the the alphanumeric plugin.

Comment: I suspect you are not adding a reference to jquery

Answer (score 0):

you can have a javascript to check on a event that may use isNAN function to see the values entered are numbers or not.

if(isNaN($('input[type=text]').val())

bye the way isNaN means Not a Number

Comment: `$('input[type=text]').val()` will always return a string, even if only integers are entered, so this will always return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet by far is to leverage the work of someone who's already done this for you, via a validation library and/or input masking library. Don't reinvent the wheel, several nice round ones, with rims to suit just about any car, have already been invented for you.

Not linking a specific one here because that's not really the point, a search on "javascript form validation library" will find quite a few.

**Edit** I hadn't looked for a while, I have to say I like the look of [this one](http://yav.sourceforge.net/en/index.html). Both validation and masking, and not library-specific (though there's a jQuery plug-in available if you like). Again, linking them isn't really the point, but it looked cool enough to shout out.

Answer (score 0):

The code grabs the input value, and then checks from beginning to end and the {5} is number of digits (this is optional).

`function validzip(){
            txt1 = document.FormName.InputName.value;
            if (/^\d{5}$/ .test(txt1) == false){
            /* Simpler/longer alternative to this is:       if ((/[0-9]/g .test(txt1) == false) || (txt1.length != 5)){ */
                alert('Not Valid');
                return false;
            }`

```
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this with jQuery - http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

It will only allow numbers to be entered. It is also very easy to use and completely customise, not to mention light-weight.

Answer (score 0):

On the client side, start with `<input type="number">` (this will be treated as `type="text"` on browsers which don't yet support HTML5. Then use javascript (as suggested by others) for the non-HTML5 browsers.

Don't forget server-side validation too, in case people have javascript turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Already some good answers have been posted from [nc3b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2898347/3186681)
 and   [skyfoot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2898341/3186681).

But nc3b's answer may fail with input wich has leading zeros like `007` and allow exponential inputs.

And skyfoot's answer **might not allow negative values** and **might allow empty strings**.

**In order to avoid those traps** i have used below code snippet.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("input").change(function(){
      var enteredValue = $(this).val();
      var re = new RegExp("^[-+]?[0-9]+$");
      if (enteredValue != "" && re.test(enteredValue)) {
        alert("You have entered valid integer");
      } else {
        alert("This is not valid integer");
      }
        //alert("The text has been changed.");
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").change(function(){

var enteredValue = $(this).val();
var re = new RegExp("^[-+]?[0-9]+$");
  if (enteredValue != "" && re.test(enteredValue)) {
    alert("You have entered valid integer");
  } else {
    alert("This is not valid integer");
  }
    //alert("The text has been changed.");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text">
<p>Write something in the input field, and then press enter or click outside the field.</p>

</body>
</html>
```